# Advance Custom field post tile and image url

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, macfuse

I am using elementor pro with advanced custom field pro. I have Created Fron end posting for the user. I have created 3 fields Post tile -> Event Name, Post Category - > Day and Event Invitation link, What I want is when user put and submit URL it should attach to featured image and post title

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/r2fnyl front end posting url

Comment: Are you post questions or answers?

Comment: I need answere for my question new to this website